# A limit involving $e$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the result of this limit?

> $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{n^2 + 2}{2n^2 + 1}\right)^{n^2} .$$

For sure we need to use the limit below: 
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(1 + \frac1n \right)^n = e.$$

Comment: That is not an equation. I guess you want to compute a limit.

Comment: Yeaah i forgot ... it is all about limit n to infinity

Comment: Do you mean the limit if $n$ tends to infinity

Comment: yes , like in wolfram limit { n to infinity}  , the problem is that wolfram computed different answer than in my book so that's why i posted this problem here just to make it clear

Comment: What answer did the wolfram alpha gave ?

Comment: Wolfram's answer is 0 but it is wrong bcs we have got  number^infinity and in my book the answer is e^(3/2)

Comment: I probably believe wolfram's answer as $\left(\frac{n^2 + 2}{2n^2 + 1}\right)\lt 1$

Comment: No it is not , it goes for 0

Comment: I Would like somebody to give me solution step by step with the use of (1 + 1/x)^x = e

Answer (score 2):

The limit  $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+1/n)^n=e$ is not necessary here. Note that for $n\geq 2$,
$$0< \frac{n^2 + 2}{2n^2 + 1}\leq \frac{2}{3}\implies0<\left(\frac{n^2 + 2}{2n^2 + 1}\right)^{n^2}\leq \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n^2}.$$
What may we conclude as $n\to +\infty$?

Comment: but (2/3)^n^2 is not marked

Comment: we are talking about limit {n to infinity}

Comment: we can't do it like you wrote

Comment: ok i get it it may be the right answer but still dont know why the answer in my book is e^(3/2)

Comment: Maybe a  typo. $\left(\frac{2(n^2 + 2)}{2n^2 + 1}\right)^{n^2}\to e^{3/2}$

Comment: May you develop it ?

Comment: Note that $\left(\frac{2(n^2 + 2)}{2n^2 + 1}\right)^{n^2}=\left(1+\frac{3/2}{n^2 + 1/2}\right)^{n^2}$

Comment: @Quasi31 for $ n = 32 $ , the expression has the value $2.488467835021903* 10^{-308}.$ For higher values , my python script just shows $0$ , which is what we expected.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\left(\frac{n^2 + 2}{2n^2 + 1}\right)^{n^2} =\left(\frac12\frac{2n^2 + 4}{2n^2 + 1}\right)^{n^2}=\left(\frac12\right)^{n^2}\left(1+\frac{3}{2n^2 + 1}\right)^{n^2}\to 0$$

indeed

- $\left(1+\frac{3}{2n^2 + 1}\right)^{n^2}=\left[\left(1+\frac{3}{2n^2 + 1}\right)^{\frac{2n^2+1}{3}}\right]^{\frac{3n^2}{2n^2+1}}\to e^\frac32$

but

- $\left(\frac12\right)^{n^2}\to 0$

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram's answer is correct. For large $n$ your fraction is approximately $\frac12$, and $\bigl(\frac12\bigr)^{n^2}$ is very close to $0$. Perhaps you have copied the question incorrectly?

Comment: Ok , but we can make it easier to compute if we will use euler , so it would be nice if somebody could transcribe this limit in my view , bcs the answer in the book is e^(3/2) and i don't think so it is wrong answer but i can't figure it out why this is it

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \big(\frac{x^{2}+2}{2x^{2}+1}\big)^{x^{2}}$.

$A=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} e^{x^{2}\ln\big(\frac{x^{2}+2}{2x^{2}+1}\big)}$

$=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x^{2}\ln\big(\frac{x^{2}+2}{2x^{2}+1}\big)}$

Let $B=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \ln\big(\frac{x^{2}+2}{2x^{2}+1}\big)$
and $C=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x^{2}$

$B=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \ln\big(\frac{x^{2}+2}{2x^{2}+1}\big)$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \ln\big(\frac{1+\frac{2}{x^{2}}}{2+\frac{1}{x^{2}}}\big)$
$=\ln\big(\frac{1+0}{2+0}\big)$
$=\ln\frac{1}{2}$ $=-\ln2$

$C=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x^{2}$
$=+\infty$

And we have $A=e^{C\times B}$
$A=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} e^{+\infty\times\big(-\ln2\big)}$
$=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} e^{-\infty}=0$